# Select 1 Row With MIN DATETIME value from JOIN per account

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select the row with the oldest datetime value in the lastdialed column

The default DATETIME for an entry that has not been dialed is 0001-01-01 00:00:00

Currently if there is account that has entrie(s) that have NOT been dialed and  entrie(s) that HAVE been dialed-- it will select the oldest entry that HAS been dialed.

I have ran a SELECT MIN(p.lastdialed) on single accounts to verify the 0001-01-01 00:00:00 is the minimum value

Green entries should be grabbed, yellow is what is grabbed currently

[image]

I have tried with a HAVING clause and a sub-query to no avail

```
    SELECT 
    d.id,
    p.lastdialed

FROM dbase d
    JOIN phonenumbers p
    ON d.id = p.maindatabaseid

WHERE d.statusname IN ('X'
AND phonestatus NOT IN ('Y')
AND p.lastdialed = (SELECT MIN(p.lastdialed) FROM phonenumbers s WHERE s.maindatabaseid = d.id)


GROUP BY d.id
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Intended results are to grab one entry per id that has the MIN lastdialed DATETIME value

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
WHERE d.statusname IN ('X') AND
     phonestatus NOT IN ('Y') AND
     p.lastdialed = (SELECT COALESCE(MIN(s.lastdialed), '0001-01-01 00:00:00')
                     FROM phonenumbers s 
                     WHERE s.maindatabaseid = d.id AND
                           s.lastdialed <> '0001-01-01 00:00:00'
                   );
```

The subquery calculates the minimum value of `lastdialed` for each group in the outer query.

The calculation looks at the matching phone number records that do NOT have the default value and takes the minimum of those.  If none exists, then the `COALESCE()` puts the default value back in.

Comment: This worked, thank you.  I know you have no obligation to, but could you please explain to me why this works?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: After two weeks of live production, it appears this is not working to achieve the desired results. I am running into the issue presented in the question.